# How to convert Texture to VertexColor?

Tags: graphics3d

In Mathematica 11 it is not possible to Print a Graphics3D object with image textures. However, it is possible by using VertexColor. I'd like to convert a textured Graphics3D to one with VertexColor instead, is this automatically possible?

Specifically, my graphic is simply many textured polygons in 3d. In the most simple form of this question I'd like to replicate this output:

```
i = ExampleData[{"ColorTexture", "WhiteMarble"}]
Graphics3D[{Texture[i], 
  Polygon[{{-1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1}}, 
   VertexTextureCoordinates -> {{0, 0}, {1, 0}, {1, 1}, {0, 1}}]}, 
 Lighting -> "Neutral"]
```

without invoking the Texture command:

```
Graphics3D[
 Polygon[{{-1, -1, -1}, {1, -1, -1}, {1, 1, -1}, {-1, 1, -1}}, 
  VertexColors -> {Blue, Red, Green, Pink}]]
```

This obviously doesn't work.

Comment: Can you give an example of the Graphics3D you are working with?

Comment: @SumNeuron My example has a few different polygons with textures. I added a minimal example.

Comment: You will need a lot of polygons to get acceptable resolution...

Comment: @YvesKlett that is ok, so long as Mathematica doesn't crash.

Comment: I believe this is a job for a  [`ColorFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ColorFunction.html)

Comment: By print you mean 3D print?

Comment: Yes I need a 3D color printout. Sorry for the confusion.